# If I update WordPress my custom data will be deleted from the wp_users table?

Tags: custom-field, mysql, table

If I update WordPress my custom data will be deleted from the wp_users table? I add new custom field and store data to users at this field if I update WordPress and WordPress needs to update this table my custom field will be deleted?

Comment: Do you mean user meta, or did you modify the table itself to add new columns?

Comment: @TomJNowell The table itself (wp_users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, especially if the update includes changes to the user table. The only way to be sure is to test it, but for future reference:

**Never modify the scheme of WordPress Tables**

If you need to add additional information about something, WordPress provides meta, user meta, site meta, post meta, comment meta. You may know these as custom fields.

For example:

```
$value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', true );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', 'newvalue' );
$all_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id );
```

Adding columns manually to tables also bypasses the caching layer slowing things down, encourages writing manual SQL statements ( you could have used the `WP_User_Query` class! ), and stops the information being imported/exported ( custom post types get put in content exports, custom tables don't )

I recommend writing a small WP CLI command to fetch each user and store these columns as user meta instead

Answer (score 0):

No, your Custom User Data (i.e. User Meta) will remain safe in database even after you update your WordPress. I've not seen so far the WordPress Updater touching/altering the data in any of the tables.

(Just to keep posted, it's the `[prefix]_usermeta` table that holds the user related data; not the `[prefix]_users` table.

Comment: I totally understand you but in my case, i don't add this data as user meta I add this data directly info wp_users I add new field after display_name field and store the data into it, So my question are you sure that if I update WordPress this custom field not be deleted? Thank you for your time.